# Como não mostrar na saída as posições nulas de um vetor?

Tags: c, array

Como faço para que não apareça aqueles números gigantescos referentes as posições vazias do meu vetor?

#### Meu código:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

double notas[10];
double soma = 0, media = 0;
int i, P[10];
int j = 0, count = 0;

for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    printf("Digite %d: ", i);
    scanf("%lf", &notas[i]);
}

for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    if(notas[i] > 5){
        soma = soma + notas[i];
        count++;
    }
}
media = soma/ count;

for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    if(notas[i]>= media){
        P[j] = i;
        j++;
    }
}
    printf("%.2lf\n", media);


for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    printf("%d  ", P[i]);
}
return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

#### Saída:

[image: Exemplo de saída]

*Curiosidade: Qual o nome desses números grandes que aparecem?*

Comment: A resposta resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Se não souber como faz, veja o [tour]. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você e dar uma indicação que houve uma solução satisfatória. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 3):

A impressão final está imprimindo as 10 posições do *array* de notas que estiveram acima da média, só pode imprimir a quantidade de notas que foram inseridas lá, ou seja, só pode ir até `j` (nome ruim para variável já que não indica o que ela é). Uma outra solução seria só marcar como dado inválido as posições não utilizadas e depois verificar se é inválido (poderia até marcar a primeira posição inválida e fazer parar a leitura das outras), mas não gosto disto. Já não gosto nem de usar um *array* fixo para isso, mas entendo o uso em exercício. Talvez tenha algum problema de lógica também, mas não posso falar sobre isso. Algo assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    double notas[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("Digite %d: ", i);
        scanf("%lf", &notas[i]);
    }
    int j = 0, count = 0;
    double soma = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (notas[i] > 5) {
            soma = soma + notas[i];
            count++;
        }
    }
    double media = soma / count;
    int P[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (notas[i] >= media) {
            P[j] = i;
            j++;
        }
    }
    printf("%.2lf\n", media);
    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
        printf("%d  ", P[i]);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Br4AbE). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/zfcvmefh-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/Filter.c).

Os números "grandes" que aparecem é lixo de memória, já que está acessando posições do *array*  que não foram inicializados no programa ele pega qualquer porcaria que tinha na memória antes de sua execução. Em C o gerenciamento integral de memória tem que ser feito manualmente.